# How to view the executed query by tablegateway in zf2

Tags: php, sql, zend-framework2, zend-db

This is my controller action

```
 public function updateAction()
{
     // Retrieve parameters
    $event = $this->params()->fromRoute('event', null);
    $subUnitId = $this->params()->fromRoute('subunit', null);
    $employeeId = $this->params()->fromRoute('employee', null);
    $status = $this->params()->fromRoute('status', 0);

    // Construct data array for database update
    $data = array(
        'os_event_id' => $event,
        'sub_unit_id' => $subUnitId,
        'employee_id' => $employeeId,
        'created_by'  => $this->getCurrentUser(),
        'status'      => $status,
    );

    // Update status to database


    $this->getOsfTable()->updateStatus($data);




    $url = $this->getRequest()->getHeader('Referer')->getUri();
    return $this->redirect()->toUrl($url);
}
```

and this is my model

```
public function updateStatus($data)
{

        $this->tableGateway->update(array(
            'status'     => $data['status'],
            'created_by' => $data['created_by'],
        ), array(
            'os_event_id' => $data['os_event_id'],
            'employee_id' => $data['employee_id'],
            'sub_unit_id' => $data['sub_unit_id'],
        ));

}
```

everytime i trigger the update function, it runs through the whole code but the update doesn't functioning. i check the passed data and parameters and it is correct so now i want to check the created query of my mode. Thanks in Advance.

Answer (score 0):

you could try this

```
$update = new Sql\Update;  // see [documentation][1] on how to build it 
...
$this->tableGateway->getSql()->getSqlStringForSqlObject($update)
```

Hope this will work ;)

Answer (score 0):

If you just need debug generated query. I would suggest to use Zend Developer Tools & BjyProfiler. First plugin give you a debug bar at bottom. While second plugin add database queries at toolbar. Then you would have list of sql queries executed on page.

See similar question : 
[How to view db queries generated by TableGateway in Zend Framework 2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13275569/how-to-view-db-queries-generated-by-tablegateway-in-zend-framework-2)